# Kendo UI Grid Inline get SUM value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had this [inline editing grid](https://dojo.telerik.com/UwUsOris). What I want to achieve went I enter a value in `basePax` and `extraBedAllow`, `maxPax` will get the SUM value of both data.

I use edit event but seem not working

```js
edit: function(e) {
  var E1 = parseInt(e.model.basePax);
  var E2 = parseInt(e.model.extraBedAllow);
  var EX = E1 + E2;
  e.model.set("maxPax", EX);
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/UwUsOris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the jQuery change function inside the edit.
Like [this](https://dojo.telerik.com/UwUsOris/3)

```
  edit: function(e) {
      $("[name='basePax'],[name='extraBedAllow']").change(
          function(){
          var E1 = parseInt(e.model.basePax);

          var E2 = parseInt(e.model.extraBedAllow);

          var EX = E1 + E2;
          e.model.set("maxPax", EX);
        });
      }
```